# ASP.NET MVC. How insert a SelectList inside an Partial?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, selectlist, mvc-editor-templates

I would like to create an partial which holds a select for a previously configured list.

in the controller I'm able to create the `SelectList` and add it to `ViewBag`.
**However `ViewBag` defined on controller are not propagated to the Partial. Partials have its own ViewBag**

for instance this POCO item class:

```
class MyItem{
    [Key] 
    public int id {get;set;}
    public int Forign_element_id {get;set;}
    public string PropB {get;set;}
}
```

And its Partial like this:

```
@model MyItem

@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropA)
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Forign_element_id, (SelectList)ViewBag.MySelectList) 
//Error! ViewBag are not propageted to the EditorTemplate

@Html.LabelFor(model => model.PropB)
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.PropB)
```

Important. Each item in the list has a Forign_element_id value. This values must be selected in select box at rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your editor template: *Instead of (Dictionary) cast it to your type; in my case, I was passing Dictionary from the calling layer; so I have used it as new SelectList(list, "Key", "Value"), change accordingly*

Name of Editor Template - **DropdownList**

```
@{
var defaultText = (string)ViewData["DefaultText"];
//var list = (Dictionary<string, string>) ViewData["List"]; -- my List was Dictionary
var list = (List<YourType>) ViewData["List"];
}
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model,
new SelectList(list, "Key", "Value"),
defaultText,
new { @class = "form-  control", style="height: auto;width:90%"   })
```

**EDIT - adding calling code**

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.YourModel, "DropdownList", new { List = ViewBag.YourList, DefaultText = "Select one item"})
```

where "DropdownList" is editor template name

Comment: ViewBag defined in the controller are not propagated to the Editor Template.

Comment: @DanielSantos - Could you try this is cshtml - *@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Forign_element_id, new { List = ViewBag.MySelectList })  * and in editor template given above, convert it to your type var list = (YourType)ViewData["List"];

Comment: I just defined the ViewData["List"] in controler, however in the Editor template ViewData is empty. Editor templates have it's own ViewBag

Comment: @DanielSantos - I just tried in my project and it worked fine: **@Html.EditorFor(model => model.MarketId, "DropdownList", new { List = ViewBag.ZoneList })**. -> where ZoneList for me is Dictionary<string,string>

Comment: @DanielSantos - updated my answer with more details.

Comment: I updated my question also. I figured out that EditorsTemplates share same ViewBag. my real problem was with partials.

Comment: @DanielSantos - my bad, I read it like you were up to create a custom editor template. So is the issue fixed?

Comment: @DanielSantos - ViewBag is shared with partials btw.

Answer (score 1):

Pass the `SelectList` as an object using one of the [overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.editorextensions.editorfor(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.Html.EditorExtensions.EditorFor%60%602%28System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper%7B%60%600%7D,System.Linq.Expressions.Expression%7BSystem.Func%7B%60%600,%60%601%7D%7D,System.Object%29) that accepts `additionalViewData`.

In the main view (assumes your model has a property named `MyProperty` which is typeof `MyItem`)

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.MyProperty, new { options = (SelectList)ViewBag.MySelectList })
```

and in your `MyItem.cshtml` template

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Forign_element_id, (SelectList)ViewData["options"])
```

Answer (score 0):

controller:

```
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetMyItemsSelectItems()
{
   return (from s in _rep.GetMyItems()
           select new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = s.MyItemName,
                Value = s.ID.ToString()
             }).AsEnumerable();
 }

 public ActionResult Create()
 {
     ViewBag.MyItems = GetMyItemsSelectItems();

     return View(new MyItem { ID = 1, Forign_element_id = 2});
 }
```

View:

```
@model App.Models.MyItem

@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ID, new SelectList(ViewBag.MyItems, 
                                                   "Value", "Text"))
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Forign_element_id, 
                        new SelectList(ViewBag.MyItems, "Value", "Text"))
```